Looking for terminology to describe a certain partial independence condition on conditional probability
I find myself in a position where for events $X,Y$ and $Z$, I might have
$$
    P(X|Y,Z) = P(X|Y)P(X|Z)
$$
I don't know what to call this, and it's difficult to search for potential phrases, since all my searches turn up more familiar and common definitions that aren't this.
I don't want to assume anything a priori on the independence or otherwise of $Y$ and $Z$, but I suspect that they will usually be independent. In that case we can derive quite easily that (assuming $P(X)P(Y)\neq 0$)
$$
P(X\cap Y)P(X\cap Z) = P(X\cap Y \cap Z).
$$
(Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the above is equivalent to the condition I'm looking at.)
It's possible to derive various other consequences, though I will not give them here.
Q: Where should I look and what is this condition called?

Edit It just struck me that, as defined, normalisation might be an issue. I'm still interested to see what there might be in the literature about the above or similar condition.

To avoid bumping this, just to point out it's obvious that a normalisation factor is needed. But I'm still curious to know if this type of thing is something that people observe.
